# showing error while upgrading ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, system

when i run **sudo apt-get upgrade** it show error given below.....

package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.23-4 is installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-1) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.23) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: Have you tried running `apt-get -f install`  as suggested in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Just run, as suggested,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

in order to try to repair the dependencies.